# Can someone tell me why I'm getting these errors and how do I resolve them?

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors

```
class IconContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const IconContent({Key? key, required this.icon, required this.label})
      : super(key: key);

  final IconData icon;
  final String label;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: const [
        Icon(
          icon,
          size: 80.0,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 15.0,
        ),
        Text(
          label,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18.0,
            color: Color(
              0xFF8D8E98,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Im getting the error stated below multiple times. Can someone help me resolve them.

> Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.\nTry making the argument a valid constant, or use 'new' to call the constructor.

This is the code Im getting the errors on. Removing const didnt do anything :(

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

const Color midNightLight = Color(0xFF1D1E33);

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const InputPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<InputPage> createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Center(
          child: Text('BMI Calculator'),
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                children: [
                  // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      colour: midNightLight,
                      // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                      cardChild: IconContent(
                        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                        label: 'MALE',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      colour: midNightLight,
                      // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                      cardChild: new IconContent(
                        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
                        label: 'FEMALE',
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                children: [
                  // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      colour: midNightLight,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
                children: [
                  // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      colour: midNightLight,
                    ),
                  ),
                  // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
                    child: ReusableCard(
                      colour: midNightLight,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class IconContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const IconContent({Key? key, required this.icon, required this.label})
      : super(key: key);

  final IconData icon;
  final String label;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: const [
        Icon(
          icon,
          size: 80.0,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 15.0,
        ),
        Text(
          label,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18.0,
            color: Color(
              0xFF8D8E98,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReusableCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.colour,
    this.cardChild,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Color? colour;
  final Widget? cardChild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        color: colour,
      ),
      child: cardChild,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`label` will get on runtime, therefore it cant be `const`

```dart
class IconContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const IconContent({
    Key? key,
    required this.icon,
    required this.label,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final IconData icon;
  final String label;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        //remove const from here
        Icon(
          icon,
          size: 80.0,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 15.0,
        ),
        Text(
          label,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18.0,
            color: Color(
              0xFF8D8E98,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It didnt work :(. Ive added the code as well to my question now can you please check that as well

Comment: Try to save the file and run again

Comment: I did but nothing changed :(

Comment: If `ReusableCard` is not using const contractor , remove `const` on `children: [ ]`

Comment: Oh wait. apparently I didnt remove the const inside the IconContent class. My Bad! It worked. Thank you for the help kind sir.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `const` from `Column's` children list. your `lable` and `icon` variable is not const and its value changes in different state because of that you can't use `const` for `Column's` children list. You also need to delete all those `const` from `Row's` children inside `Expanded` too.

Comment: I did remove it but to no avail :(

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @SyedAbdullah

Comment: I tried it but i'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: could you add ReusableCard class too? @SyedAbdullah

Comment: sure! i added the whole thing

Comment: Apparently I didnt remove the const inside the IconContent class. My Bad! It worked. Thank you for the help really appreciate it!